# Changing Post Status from Pending to Publish twice daily

Tags: post-status, wp-update-post

I have setup a function to change post status from Pending to Publish for posts in a specific category. The function works perfect if I run in under `init`, but doesn't work correctly if I run under a `wp_schedule_event`. I do know the function is being trigged on the `wp_schedule_event` because the `wp_mail` is working, but the `wp_update_post` isn't working. Is there a limit using `wp_update_post` during a scheduled event?

I added something to send me an email when the function fires with a message of how many posts were found.
I'm sure there is a more efficient way to write this, but forgive my code.

Here is my function:

```
//Schedule Event
if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'change_pending_posts' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'twicedaily', 'change_pending_posts' );
}

//Change Pending Post to Published
function change_post_pending() {
    wp_reset_query();
    $pendingargs = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'category' => 36,
        'post_status' => 'pending',
    );
    $pending_posts = get_posts( $pendingargs );
    $pending_count = count($pending_posts);
    if ($pending_count == 0) {
        $message = 'No Posts Found';
    } else if ($pending_count >= 1) {
        $message = '' . $pending_count . ' Posts Found';
    }

    foreach($pending_posts as $pend_post) {
       $id = $pend_post->ID;
       $update_post = array(
          'ID' => $id,
          'post_status' => 'publish',
          'post_type' => 'post',
       );
       wp_update_post($update_post, true);
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

    wp_mail( 'me@mydomain.com', 'Posts Pending', 'I have run the Post Pending Function! ' . $message . '!' );
}
add_action( 'change_pending_posts', 'change_post_pending' );
```

The real issue is this will run twice a day, send the email, but won't change any pending posts' post status. But if I change the `add_action` to `init` it works perfect if an anonymous user visits the site.

```
add_action( 'init', 'change_post_pending' );
```

I don't want to run it every time someone visits the website.

Any thoughts or ideas? Wondering if there might be restrictions with `wp_update_post` in a `wp_schedule_event`.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Now I'm thinking it isn't an issue with `wp_update_post`, but the problem is it isn't getting any posts on the query using `get_posts` when run during the `wp_schedule_event`. ??